# Lightweight way to gather feature requests from users and let them vote?

Tags: feedback, features, voting

To have a user-driven roadmap for my app, I am looking for a tool that let's them suggest and vote on ideas. Something like [Canny](https://canny.io/):

[image]

But since I only have a small community, I don't need any crazy features (and to pay $50 each month), I just want people to be able to post ideas and others to vote on it. I expect maybe 20 people at max to use it in the first months.

Or maybe I don't need a tool for that and there's a UX method I'm missing that helps a designer include the user in the roadmap planning from afar?

(Yes I know - testing, interviews, etc. but I'm not gonna run evaluation tests every single month to *maybe* get a new idea out of it)

Answer (score 1):

I think [Productific](https://productific.com/) offers what you are looking for. It offers a free plan for small projects.

Comment: From what I can see, you can only create your **own** ideas and then let users vote on them, right? I'd like for the users to suggest **their** ideas.

Comment: After you publish your page, there is a button on the right upper corner, where users can suggest new features, the features then appear in your dashboard page and you can promote them to ideas. After that they will appear for users to vote on it.

Answer (score 0):

Get your users to follow your Facebook Page, then create polls there.

In terms of a method to include users in the roadmap from afar: A/B Testing, even if you are using mockups/placeholders as Test Cases it can indicate user desires. If no users are clicking your `Amazing New Feature` button then it strongly suggests users aren't interested in such a feature.

Comment: Maybe that's actually not a bad idea. Since the audience is a bit more 'modern' I'd probably go for Discord rather than FB, but the poll concept stays the same. And at the same time I give people a place to chat about it.

Comment: Polls are a bad idea. They give away the vote distribution, which can and often does influence how potential voters vote. If you see something with 10000 likes and 10 dislikes, the chances are you will vote with a like. And vice versa. It's herd behaviour. Whatever tool you pick, only give information on the number of votes but not their distribution. You can and should give that information at the end after an idea has reached a specific criteria that marks it as no longer eligible for a vote (e.g. expiration date for voting or reaching a specific number of votes).